# Algolia Auto Complete Filter Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia

I am trying to filter auto complete results from Algolia back to my app.  I've added the filter to check if `draft=0` in the data i have stored in algolia.

```
autocomplete('#search-box', {hint: false}, [
{
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5}),
  displayKey: 'title',
  filters: 'draft=0',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
      return suggestion._highlightResult.title.value;
    }
  }
}
```

So far it doesn't filter and still returns draft content.  The article I don't want to show in the search is `draft: 1` in my indices on algolia.

Answer (score 4):

`filters` is parameter of the data source and not `autocomplete` itself.

Try:

```
autocomplete('#search-box', {hint: false}, [
{
  source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5, filters: 'draft=0'}),
  displayKey: 'title',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(suggestion) {
      return suggestion._highlightResult.title.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For me 'draft=0' wasn't working. I need to use a ':' instead, like 'draft:0'